# Use CDbCriteria query the database against an array of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I essentially want to search the database using an array of barcodes. Here is my query if I only have one barcode:

```
$q = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition' => '"barcode" = :barcode',
    'params' => array(':barcode' => $this->barcode),
));
```

I am trying to modify this query so that I query an array of barcodes. It would be a fairly standard array, something like `['Barcode1','Barcode2', 'Barcode3']`.

How can I modify this query I have to instead return the results for `Barcode1 OR Barcode2 OR Barcode3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an inCondition 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail

something like this

```
$q = new CDbCriteria();
$q->addInCondition("barcode",array("value1","value2"...),"AND");
```